# Can I mix direct proof with inductive proof?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, divisibility

Let's say I want to prove with induction that

> $3|n$ implies $3|n^2$

Let $n = 3k$. The statement is true for $k=1$ since $3|3$ and $3|9$

We assume the statement is true for $k=z$ so $3|3z$ implies $3|(3z)^2$. From that we know that $(3z)^2=9z^2=3x$ for some integer $x$.

To show that the statement is true for $k=z+1$: $$(3z+3)^2=9z^2+18z+9=3x+18z+9=3(x+6z+3)$$

Is this valid?

Comment: You can do anything you like as long as the end result is a working proof.

Comment: The tag ([tag:proof-theory]) is intended for questions about proof theory as a branch of mathematical logic, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-theory/info) and relevant [discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/the-proof-theory-tag-is-misused-too-often). It is not intended for all questions related to proofs. (This is why I have removed the tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Technically**, there's nothing wrong with that proof*. There's no reason you can't mix different proof techniques as long as you apply each one correctly - really, induction just demands that you prove the base case and inductive step *somehow* and there's no reason these might not require somewhat elaborate proofs.

That said, the example proof you give here will surely confuse the reader; if induction isn't necessary, it's generally best not to use it.

(*There is a typo, as $3x+18z+9$ should equal $3(x+6z+3)$, but you've missed a character)

Comment: alrighty, thank you :) I know i gave a bad example since induction here is very confusing here and redundant but i want to know just in case i encounter such problem.